# How to pull a password from Phabricator's Passphrase

Tags: phabricator

How do I pull a password saved in Phabricator's Passphrase Application?

Let's assume that we've added a password titled "My Password" to Passphrase application, now we want to reuse this password in some automation software so we need a way to pull a password using command-line or something. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it using Conduit API and passphrase.query.

To learn how to use it you should go to https://your-phabricator.com/conduit/method/passphrase.query/

1. Locate your credential key, e.g. "K1".
2. Open credential and "Allow Conduit Access".
3. Locate Conduit API CLI token on page https://your-phabricator.com/settings/panel/apitokens/
4. Use either `arc` or `curl` command to issue query:

```
echo '{"ids": [1], "needSecrets": 1}' | arc call-conduit --conduit-uri https://your-phabricator.com/ --conduit-token  passphrase.query
```

```
curl https://your-phabricator.com/api/passphrase.query \
  -d api.token=api-token \
  -d ids[0]=1 \
  -d needSecrets=1
```

5. The output can be piped further through jq:

```
curl https://your-phabricator.com/api/passphrase.query \
  -d api.token=api-token \
  -d ids[0]=1 \
  -d needSecrets=1 | jq -r '.result.data[].material.password'
```